# Do I have to call Q_DECLARE_METATYPE before calling qRegisterMetaType?

Tags: c++, qt

In the case of using a custom type in the queued signal.
What is the proper sequence of registering my custom type?

Is it necessary to call `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` before `qRegisterMetaType`?

Why do I have to register a custom type for queued signal but not for direct signal?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is necessary. 2. Because queued connection require some additional runtime initialization and possibility to do a deep copy of arguments. Btw, you may wrap a data in `QVariant` and use it as arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For Qt5:

> Is it necessary to call Q_DECLARE_METATYPE before qRegisterMetaType?

It is. The Qt doc on [qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) explicitly says :

> T must be declared with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE().

You have to register your custom type for queued signals because by registering it, Qt can make a copy of it in its event loop (which certainly uses QVariant) and pass it as argument later (when the original passed value is long since out of scope).

### For Qt6:

The plan was to be able to go without Q_DECLARE_METATYPE from Qt 6.0 onwards. But this isn't implemented entirely successfully yet. It should be done for Qt 6.5 according to this mailing list thread: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2022-July/042746.html

> Lastly, an aside: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE being effectively unnecessary was the goal for Qt 6, but is not the case yet. I consider that a bug that should finally be fixed in 6.5.

Answer (score 5):

The question is nonsense: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is not a call. It defines `struct QMetaTypeId<TYPE>`. Obviously, a call to `qRegisterMetaType<T>(...)`, or any other callable, cannot declare a type for use outside of the call site.

So, whatever `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is doing cannot be done by writing a function call. If you need the functionality provided by `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, you will have to use it.